# How to detect yii2 module used on backend or frontend

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Module can be used from both side, how can i detect this from Module bootstrap file ([`yii\base\BootstrapInterface`](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/652/how-to-use-bootstrapinterface/#hh2))

Use `$app->id` is not good idea.

Comment: You can pass some parameter to the Module instance with different values, depending on frontend/backend app's configs.

Comment: You want to kown if you have a module in you app config??

Comment: Pass some parameter to the module instance is not good idea, because module can be used in other projects. If no way to detect it from module, maybe best way to make extension with one module for frontend and second for backend for solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple function:

`function getContext() {
    return basename(Yii::getAlias('@app'));
}`

If you are running the advanced template it will return `'frontend'`, `'backend'` or `'console'`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the understanding that the application does not devides only front \ back. They can be done more than two or three. For example, we had a project that consist of: front / admin / trade / management / central_bank / public_screen. How to be in this case? 
Most likely you are thinking about the wrong module architecture.
A good solution seems like:

```
class MyModule extends Module{
 public $name_space = "";
}

//and when you define you configs:
[
    'myModule' => [
        'class' => 'common\modules\MyModule',
        'name_space'=>'application_group'
    ],
]
//also you can bootstrap it
```